# How to pass getElementById(#canvas) as a parameter to a function in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, google-web-component

I have a template code like this:

```
<img id ="canvas" src="../images/carsimage.jpg" />
```

I am trying to pass this element to a function by making something like getElementById in javascript. But I am getting an error with 'this.$.canvas'

```
initDraw(this.$.canvas);

initDraw(canvas) {
}
```

Comment: `initDraw(document.getElementById("canvas"));`

Comment: By *template code*, do you mean that HTML/code is inside your Polymer template? What error are you getting with `this.$.canvas`? Do you have a fiddle to reproduce this (e.g., with Codepen)?

Comment: this is really bad question. Are you using shadow dom or not, what is the error. Where is the problem.. Best to do is to create a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a better question and provide a codepen/fiddle/whatever, but assuming you want to call it from a component, you forgot to call the initDraw function using `this`. In Polymer v2 would be something like this:

```
ready() {
   super.ready();
   this.initDraw(this.$.canvas);    //here call this.functionName
}

initDraw(canvas) {
   console.log('canvas = ', canvas);
}
```